# Is there anyway to make git-push interactive?

Tags: git, git-push, clearcase-remote-client

On my remote git server, I have a pre-receive hook that will check-in (commit) into a clearcase repository using rcleartool's non-interactive command. What I'm working on is essentially a git to clearcase bridge. Unfortunately, this commit command requires a username and password as arguments.  Ideally, I would like the client to be prompted for the username and password when the git-push command is invoked, which will then be passed into the clearcase commit command.  However, the docs for git-push state that I can only echo messages back to the client, thus it looks like I cannot prompt the user for input.

Does anyone know of a way around this?
Has anyone tried something to make git-push seem interactive and succeed?

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having an interactive `git-push`, there is no easy solution for this.
One possible way would be to have an intermediate between the user push and the [`rcleartool`](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929) [`checkout`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/refintro.htm).

If you have [**`gitolite`**](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) for instance, based on the [forced command ssh principle](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858), you can then used that intermediate script to:

- identify who does the push (more conclusively than by just looking at a `user.name` git property)
- look for an associated password stored (crypted) somewhere on the Git server (which can be problematic if said password change on a regular basis)

With those two additional informations, the Git server can then proceed with the `rcleartool checkout` part.

Comment: Hi VonC, thanks for the quick feedback! I've thought about storing the encrypted password somewhere on the git server, but ultimately, I'll need to send the password to rcleartool checkout in an decrypted form...which is a security issue.  And I don't think rcleartool accepts encrypted passwords =(.  You wouldn't know of a way around this too would you? =)

Comment: @Ken: no I don't know a workaround, since `rcleartool` don't support `SSL` yet (https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21424834)